# Microsoft Flow: Single flow for multiple Forms

Tags: flow, power-automate, microsoft-flow, microsoft-forms

**Scenario**: I have Forms which are having about 10-15 questions, when the user submits the form, there will be a flow to save the submitted data to my DB.

**Approach**: I have created a flow to save the data once the form is submitted, Lets say the form name is A. So the flow is working for form A, I have other forms naming B,C,D etc, which are having difference only in the number of questions they hold. So A has 10 question, B has 12 question etc.

**Question**: So is there any way I can reuse the Flow which I created for Form A to work on other forms ?

Any kind of help or suggestions are totally appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft Flow has trigger action **When a new response is submitted** where you have to set Form ID to listen this event when MS Forms is submitted. And it takes only one Form ID value in this control.

So, unfortunately, there is no way right now that you can make common flow to listen all your MS Forms together. You will have to create separate flows for them.

If you have same sort of questions in all forms and you have a requirement to hide/show questions based on earlier question's answer. Then you can manage all types of forms within same form, and in this case, you can will need one flow because ultimately you have one form to manage.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, was busy with some other work, so buddy, Yes Thank you. But I have one more doubt, which is Kind of an another question, like while am sending the data to my DB, am trying to parse the input responses, for example the question is "Your age?", so when getting the responses, I can get the value but for key I have to statically type it, dynamically taking it will receive something like a unique identifier string, any solutions which you can suggest ? i can post this as a question also. If you want to.

Comment: I understand your question,but unfortunately there is no other ways to do it as it gives very limited JSON output. These keys are unique and will be same in all executions, so you can store particular key in variable or in array to extract from response like `body('Get_response_details')?[variables('Age_key')]`.

Answer (score 1):

Dikesh Gandhi is correct that one Flow has to have a specified Form.

If you do not wish to merge your Forms, you can create one Flow for Form A then "Save As" which creates a copy. The new Flow can then be edited to refer to Form B, and so on for each Form.

I have found this approach useful as the "One Flow for One List/Library/Form/Site" comes up quite a lot when using Flow/Power Automate.

Comment: I don't want anyone to be down voted for making a statement, Thank you for your suggestion, Appreciate it!! :)